# I'm trying to integrate google sign in but my project has linker error

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

this is the error i got in the console

```
Ld /Users/ajeyraj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fb_login-fyenitgjyzxqdnaelggrvofnteki/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/fb\ login.app/fb\ login normal x86_64
cd "/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my app/untitled folder/video gyan activities/fb login"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.2
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -L/Users/ajeyraj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fb_login-fyenitgjyzxqdnaelggrvofnteki/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GGLInstanceID/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/Google/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleAppUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleAuthUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleParsingUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GooglePlusUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries -F/Users/ajeyraj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fb_login-fyenitgjyzxqdnaelggrvofnteki/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/AppInvites/Frameworks -F/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GPPCore/Frameworks -F/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login/Pods/GoogleMobileAds/Frameworks -F/Users/ajeyraj/Downloads/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150910 -F/Users/ajeyraj/Documents/my\ app/untitled\ folder/video\ gyan\ activities/fb\ login -filelist /Users/ajeyraj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fb_login-fyenitgjyzxqdnaelggrvofnteki/Build/Intermediates/fb\ login.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fb\ login.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fb\ login.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.2 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -L/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/ajeyraj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fb_login-fyenitgjyzxqdnaelggrvofnteki/Build/Intermediates/fb\ login.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fb\ login.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fb_login.swiftmodule -framework Foundation -framework CoreSpotlight -framework Social -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreLocation -framework AssetsLibrary -framework Accounts -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework StoreKit -framework GooglePlus -framework GoogleOpenSource -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework FBSDKMessengerShareKit -framework GoogleSignIn -framework Bolts -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework FBSDKCoreKit -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ajeyraj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fb_login-fyenitgjyzxqdnaelggrvofnteki/Build/Intermediates/fb\ login.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fb\ login.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fb\ login_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ajeyraj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fb_login-fyenitgjyzxqdnaelggrvofnteki/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/fb\ login.app/fb\ login

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GGLContext", referenced from:
  type metadata accessor for ObjectiveC.GGLContext in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see    invocation)
```

i think I'm missing some library i don't know that it would be good if u you guys help me out
thanks

[image]

Comment: i've tried cleaning the project it doesn't work

Comment: wat do u mean trying in one device? it matters?!

Comment: Yes, actually it does matter, 'coz your error clearly says that some of your libraries doesn't support `x86_64` architecture which is your mac's.